# jquery mobile: Google maps api > allow user location > remind this preference

Tags: jquery, mobile, maps, location

I have a mobile website hosted online and builded an app around it (with a webview).
Normally when you allow an app to use your current location, the phone saves this setting and wont ask again in the future.
But with my web app (powered by jquery mobile), every time I open the app, it will ask the sam question (allow to use your current location).
Same happens when I visit the site in the browser.

Is there an option to save this preference so the app / site wont ask again?

Thanks a lot.